# Solaris make failes with 'unknown'

Tags: solaris, sunos, solaris-studio

On my system Sun Compiler is installed at below location:
/opt/SUNWspro/bin/CC

when do 'make target.o' in my project workspace, then I see below on command prompt.

CC -qoption ld -i -c target.cpp /some/path/ -I.. -I/some/path

unknown

the required target.o file is NOT being written/generated.

make is present at location '/usr/ccs/bin/make'

Not able to understand why this happening.

Can you please help me?

checked the make path and CC complier path.
I want to generate 'target.o' file.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to answer what's wrong.  What's the full command you're using to invoke `make`?  What's the contents of the makefile?  What's the contents of the C++ source file?  What's the actual full `CC ...` command that `make` runs?  Which `make` command are you actually invoking - did someone "help" everyone by putting some directory full of GNU-specific commands in your `PATH`?